# t4mvc - getting the value of a dropdownlist into the ActionResult parameters in Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I must be missing something, but...

Say I have the following Ajax form:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.TutorEditor.AddTutorCourse(Model.TutorName, TutorRoleId, CourseId),
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "TutorCourses",
                            OnBegin = "isValidPleaseWait",
                            LoadingElementId = "PleaseWait"
                        },
                        new { name = "AddTutorCourseForm", id = "AddTutorCourseForm" }))
        {    

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add Course</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllCourses)
                @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", Model.AllCourses, "-- Choose Course --", new { style = "width:180px;" })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TutorRoles)
                @Html.DropDownList("TutorRoleId", Model.TutorRoles, "-- Choose Role --", new { style = "width:180px;" })
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Course" />
        </fieldset>
        }
    }
```

I want to use it to call an Action (AddTutorCourse) that has 3 params:

1. string TutorName:  No problem here, I can get this from the model:  Model.TutorName
2. I want the value of the "TutorRoleId" dropdownlist
3. I want the value of the "CourseId dropdownlist.

Ie, calliing AddTutorCourse should look like:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult AddTutorCourse(string username, int TutorRoleId, int CourseId)
        {
            // do whatever...
            return View(service.ViewModel);
        }
```

The Question is:

At runtime, how to get the values into the following bit of code (note ??):

MVC.Admin.TutorEditor.AddTutorCourse(Model.TutorName, ??, ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
MVC.Admin.TutorEditor.AddTutorCourse(Model.TutorName, 0, 0)
```